# Automatically free memory when leaving stack

Tags: delphi, memory, memory-management

I would like to program something that helps me to free memory automatically as soon as a pointer to an dynamically allocated address space leaves the stack.
An example would be:

```
procedure FillMemory (var mypointer);
begin
  // CopyMemory, Move, etc... with data
end;

procedure MyProcedure;
var
  MyPointer : Pointer;
begin
  MyPointer := VirtualAlloc (NIL, 1024, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  FillMemory (MyPointer);
  VirtualFree(MyPointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE); // I would like to avoid this...
end;
```

I could use strings but I would also like to avoid them (which I'm not so sure if Strings in the stack get freed anyway...)
Any ideas?

Comment: strings aren't in the stack. They are a reference counted pointer to the heap.

Comment: I know but how do they get freed?

Comment: By the reference counting mechanism - once it is zero, the memory is released. This is managed by the compiler for strings and dynamic arrays. A possible solution to your question would be to use a dynamic `array of byte`, in later (2009+?) Delphi versions this is predefined as TBytes (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.SysUtils.TBytes)

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss - I believe it is the compiler that creates the necessary code.  If you're trying to do what I think you are trying to do, you would need to modify the compiler.  Without adding some type of reference counting, however,  this could be a rather dangerous 'feature' - how would the compiler know, for example, if by the end of the method your pointer still pointed to the allocated memory or if it pointed to something it shouldn't free at all?

Comment: @GerryColl I thought that dynamic arrays have to be freed too?! And I thought that something like a memory management (especially Delphi) would check if a string (almost a pointer to a Ansi/Wide array of bytes) leaves the stack, it automatically gets freed.

Comment: Do you want to make a Garbage Collector for Delphi?

Comment: interface references like `TInterfacedObject`, `IUnknown` and such. RAII pattern, yes ? look at http://pastebin.com/YFkSNn7M

Comment: Dynamic arrays are just like strings - strings are effectively a special case of Dynamic array with a first index of 1 rather than 0, although they were added earlier in D2, dynamic arrays were then added in D4. Note that the latest version of Delphi for iOS also uses a similar mechanism for object references, where it is referred to as ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). See http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2013/06/14/38948 for a history of this, and a explanation of what happens

Comment: @GerryColl - and COW! don't you forget cows when comparing strings with dynarrays! :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The: and things get much more subtle and complicated...in a good way

Comment: @GerryColl, yes, that is a somewhat perplexed, subtle and in a good way complicated bovine :-D

Comment: Is there any reason you are using VirtualAlloc directly, rather than `GetMem(MyPointer, 1024);` ?

Comment: @GerryColl I don't use GetMem cause I program without the Delphi RTL.

Comment: See the `Guard` function in the JclSysUtils unit.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss Without the RTL? This is not possible not to define at least a primitive `getmem`: it is needed by the whole class model, and all strings/dynamic array content, including low-level System.pas initialization.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Yes it is possible. You can use the Delphi 7 compiler to make obj files. After that you need the microsoft linker.

Comment: @Benjamin What do you do about System unit?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You need to use the sysinit.pas and then compile it. Here is a small example http://pastebin.com/28YJDA3Y
http://pastebin.com/vRJjJKYk
http://pastebin.com/HRiLNXD2 You need the microsoft Linker and the dcc32.exe from Delphi 7. You can add exports with the Windows SDK (e.g. kernel32.lib) e.g. `function FreeLibrary(hLibModule: HMODULE): BOOL; stdcall; external kernel32 name '_FreeLibrary@4';` and you need to add your library file in the compile.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? I'm curious.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Smaller Binary Size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comments and discussion with Arioch,

If you just want a raw memory block, use a dynamic `array of byte`. The compiler will generate code to release this memory at the end of the method:

```
type
  TBytes = array of Byte; // omit for newer Delphi versions

procedure FillMemory(var Bytes: TBytes);
begin
  { passing in here will increase the reference count to 2 }
  // CopyMemory, Move, etc... with data
end; // then drop back to 1

procedure MyProcedure;
var
  Buffer : TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Buffer, 1024);  // buffer has reference count of 1
  FillMemory (Buffer);
end;   // reference count will drop to 0, and Delphi will free memory here
```

Hope this all makes sense. It is midnight here, so I'm not feeling the most awake...

Comment: +1 This is what the OP wanted: automatic allocation of raw memory, with auto-release when code is out of scope. Good idea to speak about reference count - but with `var` it won't increase the reference count, AFAIK! :) Reference count is increased if no `var` nor `const` is used, just raw parameter. To be corrected, please. I also corrected a small typo with `TBytes = array of Byte` for a type definition.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Is it? The question calls `VirtualAlloc` with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not see the PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, you are right. But I suspect that the OP does not need it, unless he knows how to generated asm stubs on the fly, which I doubt given his question. He wrote that he "bypassed the RTL", which is a non sense - and in this case, your class-based approach won't work either. :)

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Maybe. I was taking the question at face value. Plus Benjamin has asked lots of `VirtualAlloc` questions before. Nothing in the question talks about bypassing RTL. I'm not sure where that comes from. In any case, you don't need the RTL to make classes, not for classes that implement interfaces, not for automatic reference counting of interfaces.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so you don't consider the IMPLEMENTAION of TObject and TIniterfacedObject part of RTL ???

Comment: @Arioch'The Well, `TInterfacedObject` you don't need, you can make that yourself. And you can't very well compile anything without the `System` unit unless you hack the toolchain. So, I think it's fair to assume that implementing a class is reasonable here. Where in the question does it say that I can't do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if by "make classes" you mean implement them from ground up, then you're probably correct. I read this along "type MyClass = class(TInterfacedObject)" pattern

Comment: Your answer does work but I could not use it in a non RTL project. However this answers my question just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Managed types have their references counted and when the count drops to zero, they are finalized. If you have a local variable, then when it goes out of scope, its reference count will drop to zero.

So, you can create a descendent of `TInterfacedObject` which you refer to using an interface. Something like this:

```
type
  TLifetimeWatcher = class(TInterfacedObject)
  private
    FDestroyProc: TProc;
  public
    constructor Create(const DestroyProc: TProc);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TLifetimeWatcher.Create(const DestroyProc: TProc);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FDestroyProc := DestroyProc;
end;

destructor TLifetimeWatcher.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FDestroyProc) then
    FDestroyProc();
  inherited;
end;
```

You can then use it like this:

```
procedure MyProcedure;
var
  MyPointer: Pointer;
  LifetimeWatcher: IInterface;
begin
  MyPointer := VirtualAlloc (NIL, 1024, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, 
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  LifetimeWatcher := TLifetimeWatcher.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      VirtualFree(MyPointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end;
  )
  FillMemory(MyPointer);
end;
```

When `LifetimeWatcher` leaves scope, the implementing object is destroyed and the procedure that you passed to `TLifetimeWatcher.Create` is executed.

It would be easy enough to specialise this idea to be dedicated to your use case. And that would make the code at the call site more concise.

That would look like this:

```
function VirtualAllocAutoRelease(Size: SIZE_T; Protect: DWORD;
  out LifetimeCookie: IInterface): Pointer;
var
  Ptr: Pointer;
begin
  Ptr := VirtualAlloc(nil, Size, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, Protect);
  Win32Check(Ptr<>nil);
  LifetimeCookie := TLifetimeWatcher.Create(
    procedure
    begin
      VirtualFree(Ptr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    end
  );
  Result := Ptr;
end;
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
procedure MyProcedure;
var
  MyPointer: Pointer;
  LifetimeWatcher: IInterface;
begin
  MyPointer := VirtualAllocAutoRelease(1024, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, 
    LifetimeWatcher);
  FillMemory(MyPointer);
end;
```

Comment: The OP want to bypass the whole getmem process (see his comment). So using a class is not possible for him. :) All this sounds a bit confused... but your answer is perfectly valid (even if I doubt he is using a version of Delphi handling delegates).

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez Nothing in the question indicates that classes are not viable. One of his recent questions is tagged XE4, but in any case, why should we be tethered to Delphi 7!

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez though i cannot see much practical sense i nthis, but hwy cannot you make a single-purpose IInterface-implementing class that does work without using heap manager ? Yes, you would have to override .NewInstance and so one - but that IS possible, isn't it ? Again, i do not talk about practical profit from this, only about your "not possible"

Comment: This answer is a good alternative and even considers the `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` +1

Comment: @Arioch'The Sounds like Frankenstein coding to me. And as for the question, the OP wanted to bypass the whole getmem process, so, unless  `NewInstance` is overriden, using a class is just not a solution to his concern.... but how may we find a good solution to a biased question?

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez yes, i said about dubious practical value too. But what if the very existence `.NewInstance` was the core of his question ?